# WPF: changing theme very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, themes

I'm using this code to change the theme of my wpf application:

```
ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName = value;
```

it works, but it is very slow... someone can give me some hints?

Comment: Did you try to use some WPF specific profiling tools?

Comment: What Framework are you using to do this? What code behind the scenes have you tried? What Namespace does ThemeManager.ApplicationThemeName reside in? Your question is very vague so far. Try to elaborate if you would please chap.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx